# Doing a git bisect and one of the commits doesn't build

Tags: git, git-bisect

I'm trying to find a problem in the app I'm working on and I started to do a git bisect. There are 9 steps to the bisect so 256+ commits that could potentially cause this issue.

However, one of the git bisect steps checked out a commit that wouldn't build. Because it was committed before being run and not fixed. The next commit fixed the build problem.

Is it possible to move the git bisect onto the next commit and then continue running git bisect?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Just say `git bisect skip` to "skip" the commit you can't build.  It knows what to do, and will choose another commit to try.